# How important is it for the corresponding author to be known in the field he/she is going to publish?

Tags: publications, authorship, elsevier

How important is it for the corresponding author to be known in the field he/she is going to publish? Is the academic position of the corresponding author influential? How about the co-authors?

Comment: ...important for what? Getting the paper accepted?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I am not sure if you can get the answer here that you are expecting. It is generally agreed upon that the reviewer's recommendation whether a paper should be rejected or accepted must only be based on the paper itself, and not its authors list. All reputable journals follow this principle. Having said that, I'm sure that there are plenty of cases in which more senior people "got away" with some sloppy/suggestive writing than a less well-known researcher would have. But it is hard to give provable evidence for such cases.

Comment: If you are really concerned that you paper is rejected because you are not so well-known, you may want to consider checking if there is a reputable journal in your field that does double-blind reviewing.

Comment: @DCTLib - Please turn comment 1 into an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @TheDarkSide - however, it doesn't have answer quality. Also, jakebeal already posted an answer that is already very good.

Comment: You can certainly publish without being well known (people do it all the time), but I heard it first hand from credible sources of instances when some very famous scientists received highly favorable treatment from the editors of an (at least one) elite journal.

Comment: I'm not sure why this perfectly answerable and broadly generalizable question about academia gets downvoted while requests for academic advising get upvoted :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting a paper accepted for publication in a normal journal is a matter of credibility: you must be able to convince the peer reviewers that the content of your paper is both true and novel.  Very high status journals such as Nature or Science work somewhat differently: there you cannot reach the peer reviewers until you first convince the editor that your work is "important" and "broadly interesting" enough to consider, which is a somewhat arbitrary process.

Let us consider only normal journals, however, where the bulk of all publication takes place: they still have an editorial filter, but it is generally only to ensure a submission is at least vaguely on-topic, not plagiarized, and basically sane.  These are pretty low bars to pass, though they are definitely affected by being known.  If I see a paper that has come out with a well-known PI as author and that looks like a logical extension on their prior work, I'm unlikely to scrutinize carefully for being on-topic or sanity: it would be such a blow to the reputation of the PI to misbehave there that I am comfortable to take the small risk that the reviewers might get annoyed because the paper turns out to actually be crazy or off-topic.  Not being known won't generally hurt an author here, it will just mean their paper is more likely to actually get checked for topic and sanity, rather than simply trusted.

The peer reviewers are another matter.  Peer review is a very noisy process, and even when double-blinding is used, it is often possible to have a good idea when a well-known person is involved based on the methods that they are using.  Most peer reviewers are conscientious and try to do a good and neutral job, but a (frustrating) minority are [sloppy, selfish, pushing an agenda, or abusive](https://twitter.com/reviewer_3).  Even for those who are trying to do a good job are human and thus are subject to same standard cognitive flaws we all are, like [implicit bias](http://kirwaninstitute.osu.edu/research/understanding-implicit-bias/).

All of this means that an unknown's credibility *will likely be assessed differently* than a person who is well-known as a good and careful researcher. The unknown person will generally either have to present stronger evidence to be believed or will have the evidence that they do present scrutinized more carefully.  That unknown will actually be better off, though, than a well-known person who has a history of sloppy or controversial work, who will typically have an even harder time convincing peer reviewers.

Do not draw the wrong lesson from this, however: a person most certainly *can* publish well as an unknown, early in their career, without relying on the name recognition of co-authors.  Many of us do exactly that.  It's just going to be somewhat harder than after one has already established a reputation as a careful and productive researcher.

Final note: if you ever find yourself saying "They only rejected my paper because I'm not [well-known / popular / one of the cool kids / etc]" then you are probably wrong and engaging in sour grapes kvetching.  If they rejected your paper, then you should also have been provided with clear information about what types of evidence *would* improve your ability to get accepted.  Do that instead.

Comment: @ jakebeal: Millions of thanks for your response. I couldn't agree more.

Comment: The ease of guessing authors varies from field to field and there is some evidence that reviewers often believe they know the identity of authors when they have guessed wrongly.